# Error: Can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python

Al insertar por ejemplo para sumar el 3 y el 4 en vez de devolver 7 devuelve el error: Can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

```
print("Bienvenido a la Calculadora")
print("Pulsa 1 para hacer una SUMA")
print("Pulsa 2 para hacer una RESTA")
operacion=input("")
num1 = int(input("Introduce el primer número: "))
num2 = int(input("Introduce el segundo número: "))
if operacion == "1":
    resultado=num1+num2
    print("La suma es de: " + resultado)
else:
    resultado=num1-num2
    print("La resta es de " + resultado)
```

Comment: Necesitas castear el valor a entero así `int(input....` así a los dos inputs

Comment: @Aprendiz y ¿qué hay del control de errores? ¿qué pasa si se escribe algo no numérico en `int(input ("Escribe una letra y verás"))`

Comment: A bueno @A Cedano en ese caso se administrará de otro modo, por eso no lo puede como respuesta pues solo me límite a la solución base

Comment: sigue dando error: print("La suma es de: " + resultado)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el problema que tienes es que como dice el error: "no puedes concatenar un `entero` con una `cadena`", tienes varias formas para poder mostrar el valor que fue ingresado por el usuario y son:

**Solución 1:** Le damos un formato al `print`, ejemplo:

```
print(f"La suma es de: {resultado}")
```

Explico, se agrega la f para poderle dar un formato, donde obtiene una variable o expresión que se encuentran en llaves y sustituye automáticamente el valor, esta es la forma que más me gusta y que es un poco más "fácil" de aprender y de usar, pero eso sí, fue agregada en Python 3.6, así que ten cuidado al momento de usarla.

**Solución 2:** Usamos la coma `,` para separar la cadena con el valor. Ejemplo:

```
print("La suma es de:", resultado)
```

Esta es la segunda forma y también es válida, pero si quieres agregar una cadena después de la variable habrá un espacio por defecto.

**Solución 3:** En esta forma podemos usar el método `str.format()`, ejemplo:

```
print("La suma es de: {}".format(resultado))
```

Solo es agregar los corchetes (aunque puedes agregar un 0 si gustas) y luego usar el método format para darle el formato al `string`.

**Código:**

```
print("Bienvenido a la Calculadora")
print("Pulsa 1 para hacer una SUMA")
print("Pulsa 2 para hacer una RESTA")
operacion=input("")
num1 = int(input("Introduce el primer número: "))
num2 = int(input("Introduce el segundo número: "))
if operacion == "1":
   resultado=num1+num2
   print(f"La suma es de: {resultado}")
else:
   resultado=num1-num2
   print(f"La resta es de {resultado}")
```

Para finalizar te dejo algunos enlaces con información útil acerca del print y como usarlo.

Enlaces:

- http://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/lecciones/python-cadenas.html#cadenas-f
- http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 1):

Puedes resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

- Usa la función `isdigit()` para verificar si la candena ingresada esta conformada de números
- Para hacerle un `cast` a los valores que el usuario ingresó por teclado entonces puedes usar:

  - `int`
  - `float`
- Usas un primer `if` para verificar si los valores ingresados son números, en caso afirmativo procedes a verificar con un segundo `if` que operación solicita realizar el usuario
- Finalmente dentro del `print` para concatenar la cadena de texto dle aviso mas el resultado de la suma o resta, usa el símbolo de **`,`**

Código

```
print("Bienvenido a la Calculadora")
print("Pulsa 1 para hacer una SUMA")
print("Pulsa 2 para hacer una RESTA")
operacion=input("")
num1 = input("Introduce el primer número: ")
num2 = input("Introduce el segundo número: ")
if num1.isdigit() or num2.isdigit():
  if operacion == "1":
      resultado=float(num1)+float(num2)
      print("La suma es de: ",resultado)
  else:
      resultado=float(num1)-float(num2)
      print("La resta es de ",resultado)
else:
  print("Requieres valores numéricos")
```